# Why consider the probability of selecting something when it's being selected deliberately?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There are $7$ boys and $8$ girls in a class. A teacher has $3$ items viz a pen, a pencil and an eraser, each $5$ in number. He distributes the items, one to each student. What is the probability that a boy selected at random has either a pencil or an eraser ?

As a boy is being selected deliberately, shouldn't we just bother about pencil/eraser and thus the answer is $\frac{10}{15}$?

The answer shows $\frac7{15}\frac{10}{15} = \frac{14}{45}$

Comment: Your answer of $\frac{10}{15}$ is correct. The answer seems to assume that a random student is selected although the phrasing provided states a boy is selected.

Comment: Agreed.  The probability of $\frac{7}{15}\times \frac{10}{15}$ is the probability that a *student* selected at random happens to be a boy who was given a pencil or eraser.

Comment: Perhaps this is a translation error? The answer to the question as (presumably) translated is obviously $\frac23$.